# Express server don't search static files in Angular 12 app

Tags: javascript, angular, express

### Background

I am migrating an Angular app in GKE cluster. The base docker image that I must use(company policy) does not have any options to install any new softwares like shell, Angular cli command ng etc. The base docker image has only Node installed.

There is a shared base url, let's say, [www.my-company.com](http://www.my-company.com), that everyone has to use for app deployment with a path added after the base url like [www.my-company.com/my-angular-app/](http://www.my-company.com/my-angular-app/) - all the other Angular apps must be differentiated using the path of the app.

### What I did

Since I can't run ng serve command in the base image, I added Express dependency in the package.json in Angular application and created an express server to route the traffic to Angular app.

I was following this youtube video to configure the application - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTbQphoYbK0&t=303s. The problem I am facing is to how I load the the static files in the application.

1. If I define absolute path inside sendFile method of server.js file, although the application is working, but in future, if I need to add any other files in the application, I have to create another route in server.js file.
2. I don't know how Express can search a file automatically from the static folder(and sub folders) and return only that file when needed. I defined a static folder too, but seems like it is not working.

Following is my server.js code

==============================

```
const express = require('express');

const http = require('http');

const path = require('path');

const port = 8080;

const contextPath = '/my-angular-app';

const router = express.Router();

const app = express();

app.use(contextPath, router);

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log("Listening on port: ", port);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/testapp/'));


router.get('/', function(req, res) {


    // to get index.html file

    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist/testapp/index.html'));

});

router.get('/*', function(req, res) {

     let path = __dirname +'/dist/testapp/' + req.path 

    console.log('full path: ', path);

    // To return static files based on incoming request, I am facing problem here(I think)

    res.sendFile(path);

});
```

==============================

I want Express will send any files based on file name in the request. It should also take care of nested directories in the /dist/testapp/ directory

/dist/testapp/ -> This is the directory where Angular generates code for my app after I execute ng build command

Comment: You don't need to path.resolve or to define these folders as public if your server can retrieve the file. I could just imagine there's an error with folder's path or req.path handling.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I also think the same, but can't find the error. Is there any ways Express can send back a file without using sendFile method? And if you don't mind, can you please write this code block? I need Express will have 1. context path 2. Automatic searching of static files and/or index.html. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
WEBAPP.get("/admin/script.js", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.path);
    if (req.session.username !== "Admin") return res.render("error");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/admin/admin.js")
});
WEBAPP.get("/admin", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.loggedin) return res.render("error");
    if (req.session.username !== "Admin") return res.render("error",);
    res.render("admin", {
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
        title: "ADMIN PORTAL",
        username: req.session.username,
        nav_avatar: GetImageURL(req.session.avatar, "small")
    });
});
```

There's no need to publically share /admin/script.js in my case but if a user requests this URL say example.com/admin/script.js a check for username equaling "Admin" if all is okay we sendFile.

I would maybe assume that you're not properly targeting your static files. Perhaps console.log the target.